# Possible response back from Step Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, go, response, aws-step-functions

I'm just curious if it is possible for us to get a response from a step function.
I have a few different programs written (Python, Golang), I'm just curious if I can invoke a step function and then get the response back from it. The Step Function has a few lambdas in its flow, then it eventually has more stuff happening after it but I just want to get info from the step function that is invoked.
Just curious if this is possible in some way and if not, are there any workarounds that have been done to get the info I need?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. You would have to have second URL for your app which you would pull for some results. Your SF would have to populate, lets say a DynamoDB, with the results that you want.

Comment: So then there’s no chance I can get a response back from my step function? That doesn’t sound right, I thought I saw something where we check the describe execution response or something and can read the response back